# How to call a REST API in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, api, curl, laravel-5.4

I have developed a `laravel` project in which I want to call a `REST API` to pass a form inputs to it by the use of `CURL`. After submitting a form by user, form data are passed to a controller, then `API` is called but I receives false or null as response.
The data must be sent to `API` as below, as you see the data must be a `json` in an `array`(image is not a file, it is a path):

```
[{
    'title' : 'title',
    'body' : 'description',
    'source' :  'http://www.google.com',
    'date' : 1503845107465,
    'active' : true,
    'image' : '758.jpg',
    'category' : [
        1
    ]
}];
```

here is a part of my controller, `$data` is build out of form inputs.

```
$data = [
       'title' => 'title',
       'body' => 'description',
       'source' =>  'http://www.google.com',
       'date' => 1503845107465,
       'active' => true,
       'image' => '758.jpg',
       'category' => [
        1
        ]
    ];
        $curl=curl_init('http://x.x.x.x/rest/test');

        $send = json_encode([$data]);
        //return $send;
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send);

        try{
            $res = curl_exec($curl);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        dd($res);
```

`$res` is false.
It must be mentioned that the code in controller works on localhost but it does not work on `linux` server.

I also used `ixudra/curl` but it does not solve my problem and it returns null.

I got this error Failed to connect to x.x.x.x Permission denied. I can ping this `url` and I can send data with `curl` to this IP in a `php` file. but in `laravel` I get this error

Comment: If it works locally but not on the hoserverst, it may not be your code, or at least not directly. Output the headers and see what the response is there.

Comment: header and body of response are false.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at guzzleHttp, it handles all the curl details for you. Are you able to ping the url from the server?

Comment: To get response comment out the curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: @rypskar Yes I can ping the URL. I will check guzzleHttp.

Comment: @Milad I comment it out but I again received false.

Comment: @rypskar I got this error Failed to connect to x.x.x.x ! I can ping this url and I can send data with curl to this IP in a php file. but in laravel I get this error.